# Finding the Green's function for $y'' + y' = f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this ODE:
$$y'' + y' = f(x)$$ with $y(0)=0$ and $y'(1) = 0$. I'm trying to find the Green's function.

I multiply through by $G$, integrate over the domain and then use integration by parts to find the adjoint and I'm left with:

$$ \int\limits_0^1 y(G'' - G')dx + G(1)y(1) = \int\limits_0^1 Gfdx$$.

(This is after choosing the boundary conditions for G: $G(0) = 0$ and $G'(1) = 0$ so that most of the boundary terms from the integration by parts are zero. And then I would choose $G'' - G' = \delta (x-\xi)$.)

My question is, how do I deal with the $G(1)y(1)$ term? I haven't encountered a problem before where all the boundary terms aren't nicely zero.

I've also tried this problem using the variation of parameters method and I see that we get an integral condition, I'm guessing this has something to do with it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

We get
$$y'+y = \int_0^x f(t)dt + c \implies \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(e^xy\right) = e^x \int_0^x f(t)dt + ce^x$$
This gives us
$$y = e^{-x} \int_0^x e^s \int_0^s f(t)dt ds + e^{-x} \int_0^x c e^{-s}ds + c_1$$
Simplifying, we get
$$y = \int_0^x \left(1-e^{t-x} \right) f(t) dt + e^{-x} \int_0^x c e^{-s}ds + c_1$$
Hence, the Green's function is $G(x,t) = 1-e^{t-x}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can follow the reasoning well enough, but I'm more wondering why my method doesn't work? also how would you satisfy the boundary conditions with your solution?